# BeautifulSoup - Web crawler searches duplicated links

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to make web crawler finds external hyperlink of the web page recursively.

With following code, crawler works well but it searches and inserts the link that already saved in database.

I added `SELECT` query to count rows that have same link but nothing has changed.

What is the problem?

**Code:**

```
def add_external_links(bs_obj, scheme, exclude_url, title):
    for link in bs_obj.find_all("a", href=re.compile("^(https|http|www|\/\/)((?!" + exclude_url + ").)*$")):
        if link.attrs["href"].endswith("/"):
            link.attrs["href"] = link.attrs["href"][:-1]

        # Get matching rows
        select_in_return = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM external_links WHERE href=%s;", (link.attrs["href"],))

        if select_in_return == 0:
            if link.attrs["href"].startswith("//"):
                cur.execute("INSERT INTO external_links (idx, href, title, contents) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s);",
                            (0, scheme + "://" + link.attrs["href"][2:], title, "Temp contents",))

                conn.commit()

            else:
                cur.execute("INSERT INTO internal_links (idx, href, title, contents) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s);",
                            (0, link.attrs["href"], title, "Temp contents",))

                conn.commit()


def split_address(addr):
    address_parts = None

    if "https" in addr:
        address_parts = addr.replace("https://", "").split("/")
        if "www" in address_parts[0]:
            address_parts = address_parts[0].replace("www.", "")
    elif "http" in addr:
        address_parts = addr.replace("http://", "").split("/")
        if "www" in address_parts[0]:
            address_parts = address_parts[0].replace("www.", "")

    return address_parts


def get_random_external_links(starting_page):
    html = urlopen(starting_page)

    try:
        bs_obj = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    except AttributeError as e:
        return -1

    title = bs_obj.find("title")

    # Get scheme, netloc and title of URI and pass them to add_external_links()
    add_external_links(bs_obj, urlparse(starting_page).scheme, split_address(starting_page)[0], title.get_text())

    cur.execute("SELECT href FROM external_links ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;")
    fetch = cur.fetchall()
    selected_tuple = str(fetch[0][0])

    if selected_tuple.startswith("b'"):
        selected_tuple = selected_tuple[2:]

    if selected_tuple.endswith("'"):
        selected_tuple = selected_tuple[:-1]

    return selected_tuple


def find_random_link(url):
    get_link = get_random_external_link(url)

    if get_link == -1:
        return -1
    else:
        return find_random_link(get_link)
```

**DB "external_links":**

```
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| idx      | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | <null>  | auto_increment |
| href     | blob         | NO   |     | <null>  |                |
| title    | varchar(255) | NO   |     | <null>  |                |
| contents | blob         | NO   |     | <null>  |                |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

[image]

Comment: You should check if links exist with fetchone():  `if select_in_return.fetchone()`. It will return None if there are no matches.

Comment: can you please print query after executing it and tell us query in comment below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of different uri style.

```
 - https://www.google.com
 - https://google.com
 - http://www.google.com
 - http://google.com
 - //www.google.com
 - //google.com
 - www.google.com
```

These seven links are same address, but it isn't checked until enter into `if select_in_return == 0:` block. After executing `INSERT INTO` query they will become same address, but they are considered as different link while executing `SELECT` query, so duplicated link is stored.

**Solution:**

```
def add_external_links(bs_obj, scheme, exclude_url, title):
    for link in bs_obj.find_all("a", href=re.compile("^(https|http|www|\/\/)((?!" + exclude_url + ").)*$")):
        # Remove protocol(https:// or http:// or //) and host(www.) from URI
        if link.attrs["href"].startswith("//"):
            link.attrs["href"] = link.attrs["href"][2:]
            if "www" in link.attrs["href"]:
                link.attrs["href"] = link.attrs["href"].replace("www.", "")
        elif "https" in link.attrs["href"]:
            link.attrs["href"] = link.attrs["href"].replace("https://", "")
            if "www" in link.attrs["href"]:
                link.attrs["href"] = link.attrs["href"].replace("www.", "")
        elif "http" in link.attrs["href"]:
            link.attrs["href"] = link.attrs["href"].replace("http://", "")
            if "www" in link.attrs["href"]:
                link.attrs["href"] = link.attrs["href"].replace("www.", "")
        elif "www" in link.attrs["href"]:
            link.attrs["href"] = link.attrs["href"].replace("www.", "")

        # Remove trailing slash
        if link.attrs["href"].endswith("/"):
            link.attrs["href"] = link.attrs["href"][:-1]

        # Reassemble URI
        link.attrs["href"] = scheme + "://" + link.attrs["href"]

        # Get rows matching with URI
        select_in_return = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM external_links WHERE href=%s;", (link.attrs["href"],))

        # Add URI to database if it is not duplicated
        if select_in_return == 0:
            cur.execute("INSERT INTO external_links (idx, href, title, contents) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s);",
                        (0, link.attrs["href"], title, "Temp contents",))
            conn.commit()
```